# PHP array navigation

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array with this structure and I am trying to get one element from it:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [description] => 
        [idProduct] => Array
            (
                [id1] => 7227
                [idProduct] => 3
            )

        [idSite] => 2592
        [name] => Parcela Azul
        [picture] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [description] => 
        [idProduct] => Array
            (
                [id1] => 7227
                [idProduct] => 8
            )

        [idSite] => 2592
        [name] => Apartamento 2 pax
        [picture] => 
    )
)
```

so, I got a variable that stores the array. My question is:

Why this works:

```
$test = $categorias[0];
$test2 = $test['name'];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($test2);
echo "</pre>";
```

Result: Parcela Azul

And this doesn't:

```
$test = $categorias[0]['name'];
echo "<pre>";
print_r($test);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: My guess is, a typo somewhere... do you show Notices?

Comment: What is the output of the second code?

Comment: Well if you work on thing like this you would probably seen alot of poltergeys things out there: that code that used to work now doesn't and viceversa. So now when i was going to post the output of the second code it worked fine. Please don't be cruel.

Comment: Don't give index values 0,1. This values are system generated keys. Remove them your code will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here What I have get

```
$test = array
                    (
                        array(
                              'name'=>'Rohit'  
                        ),
                        array(
                            'name'=>'go'
                        )
                    );
        echo $test[1]['name'];
```

If you are playing with the system index then it will create some issue. You should remove the system indexing values.

Comment: The indexes are generated by printing the array, using `print_r`

Comment: No problem then too. As I have tested this in my local environment. This is working fine